# Find if series converge ( series containing complex numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here I try to determine whether series converge:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(z-2i)^{3k}}{k^3 2^k}$$

$$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| =\left| \frac{(z-2i)^{3(k+1)} 2^{k} k^3}{(k+1)^32^{k+1}(z-2i)^{3k}}\right| = \frac{1}{2} \left|\frac{z-2i}{k+1}\right|^3 \left|\frac{k}{(z-2i)^3} \right|^k =\frac{1}{2(k+1)} \left(\frac{k}{|z-2i|}\right)^k $$

It cannot be less than 1 for large $k$, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: The second-to-last expression doesn't look right. Where does the $k^k$ factor come from in the numerator, and where does the $|(z-2i)^3|^k$ come from in the denominator?

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake while simplifying $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$.  It should be  $\left| \frac{(z-2i)^{3(k+1)} 2^{k} k^3}{(k+1)^32^{k+1}(z-2i)^{3k}}\right| = \left| \frac{(z-2i)^{3}  k^3}{2(k+1)^3}\right|$, where $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{{(k+1)}^3}{k^3}=1$.  So  $\left| (z-2i)^{3}\right| < 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some errors in your simplification. A corrected version is as follows.
$$\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|
&= \left| \frac{(z-2i)^{3(k+1)}2^k k^3}{(k+1)^3 2^{k+1}(z-2i)^{3k}} \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left| \frac{k}{k+1}\right|^3 \left| z-2i \right|^3
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore 
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| = \frac{1}{2}|z-2i|^3$$
So convergence will hold if $|z-2i|^3 < 2$.

Comment: @Burgo Why does $\frac{k}{k+1}$ cancel out?

Comment: Because $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k}{k+1} = 1$, and therefore by continuity of the $|\cdot|^3$ function, $\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{k}{k+1}\right|^3 = \left| \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k}{k+1} \right|^3 = |1|^3 = 1$.